# Specific value in an array does not work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a question about my array. How can I get only data of milestone in my milestone array?

I have a query which is a prefixed array. I get data of milestones and milestonefases (this is milestone parts).

This is my code:

```
$stones_fases = array();
while ($row = $db->fetchassoc($result)){
    $milestonefase = array();
    $milestone = array();

    foreach ($row as $mkey => $mvalue){
        $milestone[$mkey] = $mvalue;
        foreach ($row as $fkey => $fvalue){
            $milestonefase[$fkey] = $fvalue;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']])){
        $stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']] = $milestone; //['client']['milestone_verkocht_id']
    }
    $stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']][$milestonefase['milestonefase_id']] = $milestonefase['milestonefase_titel'];
}
```

I **get** this:

```
Array
(
    [int] => Array
        (
            [milestone_id] => int
            [milestone_titel] => string
            [client] => string
            [milestone_verkocht_id] => 99
            [milestonefase_id] => 10
            [milestonefase_titel] => string
            [milestonefase_milestone_id] => 6
            [10] => string
            [11] => string
        )
)
```

But I **want** this:

```
Array
(
    [int] => Array
        (
            [milestone_titel] => string
            [client] => string
            [milestone_verkocht_id] => int
            [10] => string
            [11] => string
        )
)
```

My query is this:

```
$project = $_COOKIE['project'];
$query = " SELECT 
                 a.id AS `milestone_id`, 
                 a.titel AS `milestone_titel`, 
                 a.client AS `client`,
                 a.verkocht_id AS `milestone_verkocht_id`,

                 b.id AS `milestonefase_id`, 
                 b.titel AS `milestonefase_titel`,
                 b.milestone_id AS `milestonefase_milestone_id`
                 FROM `milestones` a
                 INNER JOIN `milestone_parts` b ON a.id=b.milestone_id
                 WHERE a.verkocht_id = '{$project}' ";
$result= $db->query($dbh, $query);
```

Comment: can yo give the array you are getting by $db->fetchassoc($result)...?

Comment: `$result= $db->query($dbh, $query);`

Comment: while ($row = $db->fetchassoc($result)){
  echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
 }

Comment: run this query before while loop and paste result you get. whit that.

Comment: Where did you get that `$array` from, i dont have that?

Comment: sorry replace $array to $row

Comment: Yes i get this:     

    [milestone_id] => 6
    [milestone_titel] => Registranten systeem portaal functionaliteit geven
    [client] => ninebits
    [milestone_verkocht_id] => 99
    [milestonefase_id] => 10
    [milestonefase_titel] => Functiebeheer CMS maken
    [milestonefase_milestone_id] => 6

Comment: my question was : I want in my array `$milestones` the following values : `client`, `milestone_verkocht_id` and `milestone_titel`

Comment: So your output of the query is this: [milestone_id] => 6 [milestone_titel] => Registranten systeem portaal functionaliteit geven [client] => ninebits [milestone_verkocht_id] => 99 [milestonefase_id] => 10 [milestonefase_titel] => Functiebeheer CMS maken [milestonefase_milestone_id] => 6

And you want to keep only the 3 fields :client, milestone_verkocht_id and milestone_titel

In the question what are the fields 180 195 196? Are they static or you get them from somewhere and create dynamic the keys?

Comment: those are `milestonefase_id`. I need those. I want `milestonefase_id` and in that i want `milestonefase_titel`. i did it by this way: if (!isset($stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']])){
        $stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']] = $milestone; //['client']['milestone_verkocht_id']
    }
    $stones_fases[$milestone['milestone_id']][$milestonefase['milestonefase_id']] = $milestonefase['milestonefase_titel'];

Comment: You need to know how your data is structured to loop through it. So publish the data you received

Comment: I edited my question sir

Comment: Many developers who volunteer on SO are able to convert a resultset to an array structure.  The fact that none of us can answer your question should convey to you that it is "unclear what you are asking".  For this reason your question may be closed and you will not receive the support you desire. Your use of nested loops is a red flag that your process is not refined.  Please create a sqlfiddle that contains the minimum necessary data for your query to produce a complete result set.  Then explain the exact array(s) that you require for your project. Do this and I guarantee I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem!

If i do this:

```
while ($row = $db->fetchassoc($result)){
    $stones_fases[$row['milestone_id']]['milestone_titel'] = $row['milestone_titel'];
    $stones_fases[$row['milestone_id']]['milestone_client'] = $row['client'];
    $stones_fases[$row['milestone_id']]['milestonesfases'][$row['milestonefase_id']] = $row['milestonefase_titel'];
}
```

I get what i expected:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [milestone_titel] => Beheer opleveren
            [milestone_client] => stackoverflow
            [milestonesfases] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Menu bouwen
                    [2] => Pagina beheer CMS
                    [3] => Projecten CMS
                    [4] => Portfolio
                    [5] => Footer inbouwen
                )

        )

)
```

Look at that bunch of code what I wrote a day ago.

Do you see that nonsens of code what I wrote?

Take a look at my code which I wrote 1 minute ago!

I was struggling this for 3 days and now I solved my own problem!